# Twitter client for Mac that can show in growl the result of a search

Tags: macos, twitter, growl

Is it there any twitter client for Mac that can show in growl the result of a search? For instance, in real-time show in growl all results pertaining to the hash tag `#Apple`.

Comment: Why would you want to fill your screen with Growl notifications you'd have to click away individually or, alternatively, that disappear within seconds?

Comment: I have my reasons for that. I want to get news about some specific hashtag, which is updated every 2 or 3 hours and I want to forget about checking out constantly the twitter client. Moreover, you can configure growl so that after 2 or 3 seconds notifications vanish, without clicking them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do they have to be Growl notifications?

Tweetdeck has to option to add a 'search'-column and let's you set the notification-options for that.

This results in a notification every time a new tweet matches your search parameters (and twitter's streaming feature makes it very fast)

[image]

Comment: thanks it looks good! but I honestly need the growl notifications!

Comment: ok I think this is the best solution available now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [Syrinx](http://www.mrrsoftware.com/MRRSoftware/Syrinx.html), a twitter client designed for Leopard (OS X 10.5+).

Here is what it says :

> **Twitter Search:** The ability to search all of Twitter is integrated
>   right into the client.  Open a new
>   search window, search for a term and
>   receive a timeline of those search
>   results.  Every few minutes Syrinx
>   will search for new results and add
>   them to the search result window. 
>   Have as many search windows as you
>   want.
>
> **Growl Integration:** Use Growl notifications to stay caught up on
>   your tweets without switching
>   applications.  Click a Growl
>   notification to book that tweet, or
>   use it to switch to Syrinx.

The application is free (donationware), although it does contain this warning :

> I am currently not accepting donations
>   for Syrinx development as it's a very
>   real possibility that Twitter will
>   soon force all non-official clients to
>   cease and desist.  As such I can no
>   longer guarantee continued
>   development.

<sup>Not having a Mac, I cannot test this application</sup>